# curl w3c-markup-validator localy is slow, how do I make it faster?

Tags: apache, soap, curl, w3c

I am using curl like this:

curl -s -F "uploaded_file=@/path_to_file;type=text/html" -F output=soap12 http://localhost/w3c-markup-validator/check >text.xml && xsltproc script/guilbep_soap_w3c.xsl text.xml

xsltproc is fast; but curl is not.

does it come from the fact that w3c-markup-validator is local? or from w3c-markup-validator itself? Or from curl and I can do something?

I would like to test more than 6000 xhtml.. and if I have to wait 2 sec between each .. more than 1 hour.. I can wait.. but I don't like it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that it is quite probably that the 2 second delay is because you transfer the file over http. Is it possible to run the validator locally, without sending it to a webserver?

Comment: the validator is on my local apache2 server. you mean like an executable? I think it's this one: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/check   
but how do I use it with curl?
thanks.

Comment: I think it's another question so I'll ask elsewhere :) thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I meant running it like an executable instead and if you would use the executable you wouldn't use curl.

Comment: Yes I am starting to understand it, it's a cgi script in perl.